# PowerMock giving ConstructorNotFoundException

Tags: java, junit, powermock

PowerMock giving `ConstructorNotFoundException` on:

```
BufferedReader mockObject = PowerMock.createMockAndExpectNew(BufferReader.class, EasyMock.anyObject());
```

When I have updated the Java version to JDK getting `ConstructorNotFoundException`.

PowerMock version is 1.6.5.

With JDK 7 it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and using EasyMock.eq(classInstance) instead of Easymock.anyObject() fixed it.